# How to know which user has marked a reply as Best Reply in a Sharepoint Community

Tags: community, community-site

I recently created a community site in Sharepoint 2013 and noticed that when someone marked a reply as Best Reply, I cannot see which user has done this action.

Is there a way to get this information ?

Comment: I found that there is a field that shows the ID of the best reply (or best answer). When a moderator mark a reply as best answer, the list item of the question is modified. So at this time, the field « Editor » (Modified By) contains the name of the user who marked the answer as best reply. I supposed that I will be able to use a workflow that trigger when the question is modified to get this information and save it somewhere in another field.