# Q&A in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, discussion-board

Is it possible to have a Q&A in Sharepoint Online?

As in, for someone to ask a question and there might be a discussion happen and when the question is answered or marked as answered an email is then sent out rather than when the question is first asked?

Comment: Are you looking more for a reddit/Facebook-wall type of Q&A or stackexchange type of individual question + answers below?

Comment: Hi, I'm open to what ever will meet my requirement. I know there is a news-feed option but the main requirement is to mark the question as "answered" and then the users get notified.

Comment: SharePoint's discussion board includes the *best reply* option to promote an answer. A comment in this question describes a little bit how you could probably create a workflow when a best reply has been chosen: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/146580/how-to-know-which-user-has-marked-a-reply-as-best-reply-in-a-sharepoint-communit

Comment: In my discussion board I cannot see a "reply" option and I have full permissions. When I click into a title of an article or discussion posted all I see is the option to close? The best reply option sounds like a useful feature though

Answer (score 1):

You can create a "Discussion" that can cater to your requirement. Thought the email being send after marking an answer is not possible.